# How does a record label work?

Tags: record-labels

A lot of artists have their records associated with a record label. When I search for records under a specific label, the results usually resemble or relate to each other, so I use it as a way to search for new music.

What exactly is the function of a record label besides the one above and how do they relate to the artists and the recording companies?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Record Label:](http://musicians.about.com/od/ip/g/recordlabel.htm)

They manufacture, distribute and promote music from a artist that is under their label. There are 2 types:

- Independent.

> Indie record labels are independent companies that do not have a
>   corporate backer.

- Major.

> Major labels are large corporations often owned by a parent company,
>   like Sony.

---

Taking from [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_label)

**How do they relate to the artists and the recording companies?**

> Within the music industry, most recording artists have become
>   increasingly reliant upon record labels to broaden their consumer
>   base, market their albums, and be both promoted and heard on MP3,
>   radio, and television, with publicists that assist performers in
>   positive media reports to market their merchandise, and make it
>   available via stores and other media outlets

**What exactly is the function of a record label and What are they?**

> Within the music industry, most recording artists have become
>   increasingly reliant upon record labels to broaden their consumer
>   base, market their albums, and be both promoted and heard on MP3,
>   radio, and television, with publicists that assist performers in
>   positive media reports to market their merchandise, and make it
>   available via stores and other media outlets

Hope this helps!